# how does the jvm prevents infinte loop from crashing the system?

Tags: java, loops, jvm

I want to know how the jvm prevents infinte loop from crashing the system. The internal process which takes care of it.

Comment: It doesn't prevent it... And infinite loops don't crash systems, it just hangs (unresponsive) the application...

Comment: Why would an infinite loop crash the system? Maybe if the system was waiting for your program to do something, and the infinite loop stops your program from doing that thing. But modern systems don't usually wait for programs to do things.

Comment: Why would an infinite loop crash the SYSTEM?

Answer (score 1):

The VM will not prevent, and even it wants to, it have no clue whether it should stop the loop execution or not, unless when it sees an error within the loop which are not handled by the logic within. Could be memory full, stack overflow, IO error.

Some application were intended to have an infinite loop. For example, a scheduler application that loops infinitely and checking for schedule for something in their loop logic. Or a web server, who continuously waiting for web page request. These application will loop indefinitely and the VM must allow them to do so. As long as the logic do everything "properly" like manage its own resources responsibly.

It is the responsibility of the application to prevents bad thing to happen by doing infinite loop, not the VM. VM only to ensure that the execution of program instruction were properly, as intended by the application, and manage the resource handling (memory, time, I/O, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When ever we install Java on our OS at that time some default memory size is provided to the JVM to run and do its process, If any of your program goes into a infinite loop then it may be possible that it use the complete memory provided to JVM but it can not use the memory beyond that and this only makes your system to work slow because of the number of thread and the number of method call present on the call stack. But the system never crashes. The general error in that scenario is StackOverFlowError and it is a way in which java has ensured that any program will not be using more than the memory allocated to JVM.

Comment: There are no 'statements on the call stack'.